# Add a label to a specific data element in MSChart

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I was wondering is it possible to label a specific value plotted onto my chart. I do not mean and X-axis or Y-axis label, I am trying to point to a specific data value wihin my chart and label it.

For example if my Y-axis is from 0 to 100, and I have a value on my chart that is 60, i was wondering is it possiblt to point to this value (with a line or arrow) and give it a label (e.g £60)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to modify the [DataPointLabel Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0zy7034%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) for the point in your collection. e.g.

```
MSChart1.Plot.SeriesCollection[0].DataPoints[0].DataPointLabel.Text = "£60"
```

Comment: not exactly, im not wanting to edit the labels aleady there, Im wanting to add a new label to my chart if a specific value occurs (e.g. 60) so each time the value 60 is plotted I can have a lebel which points to that value on my chart.

Comment: You mean a single label pointing to multiple points? ...or "£60" labels on each datapoint?